# Cannot deregister service in Consul development instance

Tags: python, consul

I started a local development Consul instance using `./consul agent -dev`. I access the instance using [python-consul](https://python-consul.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#). The Consul UI is accessible, I can register a service and see it in the UI, ... So everything works fine, but: I cannot deregister a service. If I do see, I see a "method not allowed" in the Consul console logs.

The plain development instance should not have access control at all, as far as I understood. So I have no idea what I might be doing wrong. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

In consul, deregister need to send a put method, yet in python-consul it sends a get method.
A workaround for this is to change the deregister function, **from get to put**, in **base.py** file which you can find in "python path\Lib\site-packages\consul\"

```
def deregister(self, service_id):
    """
    Used to remove a service from the local agent. The agent will
    take care of deregistering the service with the Catalog. If
    there is an associated check, that is also deregistered.
    """
    return self.agent.http.put(
           CB.bool(), '/v1/agent/service/deregister/%s' % service_id)
```